# What is => called in Scala?

Tags: scala

I know `=>` in Scala is used in function literals and means "convert the thing on the left to the thing on the right". But what is the symbol actually called?  Equals, implies, lambda?  What?

Comment: How about `arrow` or `makes`?

Comment: In various languages I've seen it referred to as a "fat arrow" as opposed to the "thin arrow" `->`. See this on [fat arrows in javascript](http://css.dzone.com/articles/javascript-fat-city) or this on [fat vs thin arrows in Kotlin](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2012/01/the-great-syntactic-shift/)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I remember having read the term "rocket" somewhere, probably in the book [*Programming Scala*](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/) by Dean Wampler and Alex Payne. I found [this related answer from Bill Venners on a forum](http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=282&thread=239168&start=0&msRange=100):

> I asked Martin Odersky a while back what he called this, and he said "right arrow". Ron Hitchens suggested the name "bullet" to me a couple months ago. I used that here and there, but it didn't seem to stick. About 2 weeks ago I asked some Ruby guys what they call it, and they said "hash rocket". The reason for "hash" is Ruby uses it for mapping keys to value, i.e., "key => value" in Ruby is like "key -> value" in Scala (but untyped in Ruby), and of course -> in Scala is a library abstraction, not part of the language.
>
> So I suggest we call it "rocket". It's more exciting and less violent than bullet, and we can put an adjective in there to differentiate the various uses in Scala: there's "function rocket" in anonymous functions, maybe a "case rocket" in a case clause in match expression or partial function, etc.

So the "official" term used by Odersky is *"right arrow"*.

Answer (score 13):

Also commonly called "fat arrow"

UPDATE: oh I just noticed that Paolo Falabella mentioned it in a comment above. Whatever, it is just as as well to have a proper answer here as "fat arrow" is indeeed a very common name for it.

Comment: Coffeescript has both 'fat' and 'thin' right arrows. The adjective is essential to differentiate between them. Scala is essentially in the same situation.

Answer (score 6):

In the scala docs ([A Scala Tutorial for Java Programmers](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-for-java-programmers.html)) it is referred as `right arrow`

Answer (score 1):

In Book, `Programming in Scala` by Martin Odersky, Lex Spoon, Bill Venners it is mentioned as **Right arrow** or **Rcket**

=> (right arrow, or “rocket”)

- in function literals, 68
- in import statements, 270–271
- in self types, 563
- in match alternatives, 164
- in this aliasing, 659